# Soft linked .vimrc and .vim Mavericks not working

Tags: vim

I'm trying to share my vim plugins, in my .vim file, and my .vimrc across multiple machines. To do this, I moved my .vim and .vimrc to a folder in my user directory and use git to push and pull updates.

In my home directory I use soft links to point to these files.

```
ln -sf ~/scripts/vimrc ~/.vimrc
```

I can see these hidden files in my user directory and all seems well. The problem is, this works well on my one machine, the machine who these files originally belonged to. But, does not work at all on the other. I am running Mavericks on both machines.

I don't see any of the following files: ~/.gvimrc, ~/_vimrc

Removing these files seem to be the solution to other people's issues with the vimrc but it doesn't appear to be the problem I'm having.

Does anyone have any ideas how to get this working?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -la ~/.vimrc`. is it pointing to the file you expect it to be? (I have no problem when using symlinks on Mavericks)

Comment: Hm, yeah. It is pointing to the correct file.

Comment: My last guess would be that the permissions are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered by running `:scriptnames` that the vimrc that it was loading was not from my root directory but was `/usr/share/vim/vimrc`. And the vim folder was also not in my root directory but was `/usr/share/vim/vim73`